# JS code not working not opening on my index page

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with my code (I'm still learning to become a developer) and cant seem to figure it out! Is there anyone that can help me? When I open my index page to where my code is linked too, it's just a blank webpage. I've included my code (for a simple JS app) and please see my below code:

```
//IIFE
var pokemonRepository = (function() {
    var pokemonList = [];
    var apiUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=150';

    function loadList() {
        return fetch(apiUrl).then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(json) {
            json.results.forEach(function(item) {
                var pokemon = {
                    name: item.name,
                    detailsUrl: item.url
                };
                add(pokemon);
            });
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.error(e);
        })
    }
})();

pokemonRepository.loadList().then(function() {
    // Now the data is loaded!
    pokemonRepository.getAll().forEach(function(pokemon) {
        addListItem(pokemon);
    });

    return {
        add: add,
        getAll: getAll,
        loadList: loadList
    };
});

//function to push pokemon repository
function add(pokemon) {
    repository.push(pokemon);
}

function getAll() {
    return repository;
}

return {
    add: add,
    getAll: getAll,
    addListItem: addListItem,
    loadList: loadList,
    loadDetails: loadDetails,
    createReusableModal: createReusableModal,
    showModal: showModal,
    hideModal: hideModal
};

//Function to add list for each pokemon object
function addListItem(pokemon) {
    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerText = pokemon.creatuerName;
    button.classList.add('pokemon-name');
    listItem.appendChild(button);
    $pokemonList.appendChild(listItem)
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        showDetails(pokemon)
    })

    //Function to add another element
    console.log(pokemonRepository.getAll());
    pokemonRepository.add({
        creatureName: 'Pikachu'
    });
    console.log(pokemonRepository.getAll());

    //Creates list of Pokemon with Pokemon's name on the button
    pokemonRepository.loadList().then(function() {
                //Creates a reusable modal once
                pokemonRepository.createReusableModal();
                //Data loaded
                pokemonRepository.getAll().forEach(function(pokemon) {
                    pokemonRepository.addListItem(pokemon);
                });
```

Comment: Do you have `<ul>` or `<ol>` already written against which you are creating `<li>`?

Comment: yes, it's written in my HTML code for my webpage

Comment: your iffe doesnt return anything so `pokemonRepository` is undefined

Comment: remove the iffe out construct, but keep the contents, and call loadList directly (the iffe isnt adding any value in what you have provided here), or maybe you want a class

Answer (score 0):

`pokemonRepository` is set to the value undefined because your function doesn't return anything. So you will get a crash at `pokemonRepository.loadList()`, then execution stops. Look in the browser console as you work. You also use the variable `repository` which is never defined, I guess that should say `pokemonRepository`?

You could fix the first few lines like

```js
//IIFE
var pokemonRepository = {
  pokemonList: [],
  apiUrl: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=150',
  loadList: function() {
    return fetch(this.apiUrl).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(json => {
      json.results.forEach(item => {
        var pokemon = {
          name: item.name,
          detailsUrl: item.url
        };
        this.add(pokemon);
      });
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.error(e);
    })
  },
  add: function(x) {
    this.pokemonList.push(x);
  }
};

pokemonRepository.loadList()
```

which at least runs, but there are other parts of the code which don't make sense either.

Comment: my browser console is saying that there is an issue with the return function, I do have it there but it's not working, I've tried moving it around but I'm confused as to where it belongs in the code and how to get it to return? Also, thank you so much for your help and I have now changed repository to pokemonRepository

Comment: Yeah so you can't put a return statement anywhere outside a function as it wouldn't mean anything, so `return { add: add, getAll: getAll, ...` is going to cause an error. If there is only ever one pokemonRepository per page, I recommend making `pokemonRepository` into a plain object as I have done in the snippet above, then all of its methods can be included in it in the syntax shown. To access the properties and methods of pokemonRepository from inside itself you use e.g. `this.add()`,  from outside it you would call `pokemonRepository.add()`.

Comment: And it looks like `repository` actually meant `pokemonRepository.pokemonList`, which as you can see is referenced as `this.pokemonList` inside the re-written `add` method.